# Convert array of polygon [x,y] coordinates to SVG <path>

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

Say I have the following polygon:

```
var polygon = [[52, 57], [27, 58], [34, 21], [52, 57]]
```

How could I convert this to an SVG path element in JavaScript (NPM modules are fine also), or more specifically, the `d` part of the SVG path element, example (this doesn't match up with my polygon, just an example <path>):

```
<path d="M 95.167 154.584 L 319.986 128.067 L 178.771 305.139 L 95.167 154.584 Z"></path>
```

I tried looking it up, but all I could find was the exact opposite of what I was trying to do: converting svg  to x,y coordinates. I don't know much about how SVG works internally, so I don't even know how to approach this myself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share it as a [mcve]

Comment: Once you understand [SVG path commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d), which are very straightforward, it's just a matter of building a string and assigning the value. No packages needed.

Comment: I think svg paths are like this: `M X Y` move-to (start point). `L X Y` line-to (draw a line to). `Z` end line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands

Comment: ``0,0`` is top left, ``x,y`` is **bottom**, right

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this. You can use a Path. Path d attributes have a syntax but if all you want to do is draw a polygon then you only need to know M, L and Z (as the comments have described).

I would suggest, if you want to draw a polygon, to use `<polygon>`. The polygon `points` attribute only requires a string containing all the numbers (a flattened version of your array) delimited by commas or spaces.

```js
let polyCoords = [[52, 57], [27, 58], [34, 21], [52, 57]];


document
  .querySelector("path")
  .setAttribute("d", 
  polyCoords
    .map((c,i) => 
      i?`${c[0]} ${c[1]}`:`M${c[0]} ${c[1]}`).join(" ") + "Z"
     );

document
  .querySelector("polygon")
  .setAttribute("points", 
  polyCoords.map((c) => c.join(" ")).join(" "));
```

```css
.line {
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke: black;
  fill: #0000;
}

.red-line {
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke: red;
  fill: #0000;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polygon class="red-line" />
  <path class="line"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The `L` command does not need to be spelled out, it is assumed as a default. Take the flattened/joined array, set a `M` in front and a `Z` at the end, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Like CCProg says in the comments, you can just join the polycoordinates for a `path`, because the `L/l` (line) setting is not required:

```html
<coords-svg fill="gold" coords="[[52, 57],[27, 58],[34, 21],[52, 57]]"></coords-svg>
<coords-svg fill="green" coords="[[2, 15],[57, 58],[5, 57]]"></coords-svg>

<script>
  customElements.define("coords-svg", class extends HTMLElement{
    connectedCallback(){
      let arr = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute("coords"));
      let dPath = arr.flat().join(" ");
      let fill = this.getAttribute("fill");
      this.style.display = "inline-block";
      this.style.width = "200px";
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M${dPath}Z" fill="${fill}" /></svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```